# Extjs: filter store by array

Tags: extjs

I want to filter store by array not just a single value, I'm using filterBy but it doesn't work. Can you please help me on this?

```
       var properties = rec.get('properties').split(',');

       var store = this.getPropertyStore().load();
           store.clearFilter(false);
           store.filterBy(function(record, id) {
               return Ext.Array.contains(properties, record.get("idProperty"));

           });
```

Answer (score 0):

The load is asynchronous,put the filter into the load event:

```
var store = this.getPropertyStore().load();
    store.clearFilter(false);
    store.on('load',function(){
        store.filterBy(function(record, id) {
            return Ext.Array.contains(properties, record.get("idProperty"));
        });
    })
```